# Solve the equation for x, y and z: $\sqrt{x-y+z}=\sqrt x - \sqrt y + \sqrt z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having some trouble with this problem,

> Solve for $x,y,$ and $z$.
>   $$\sqrt{x-y+z}=\sqrt x - \sqrt y + \sqrt z$$

Here is my work so far,

$$x - y +z = x+y+z-2\sqrt{xy} + 2\sqrt{xz}- 2\sqrt{zy}$$
$$2y-2\sqrt{xy} + 2\sqrt{xz}- 2\sqrt{zy} = 0 $$
$$2(y-\sqrt{xy} + \sqrt{xz} - \sqrt{zy}) = 0 $$
$$y-\sqrt{xy} + \sqrt{xz} - \sqrt{zy} = 0$$

Answer (score 8):

Your last equation can be written as

$$ \sqrt{zx} = \sqrt{y} \left[ \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y} + \sqrt{z} \right] = \sqrt{y} \sqrt{ x-y+z} $$

Squaring both sides gives us

$$ zx = xy - y^2 + zy $$

Which simplifies to $$(y-x)(y-z) = 0 $$

Hence, we require $x=y$ or $y=z$. It is clear that in either case, the equation is satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

Even easier, your last equation can be written as:
$$
-\sqrt{y}\left(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}\right) + \sqrt{z}\left(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}\right) = 0
$$
or
$$
\left(\sqrt{z} - \sqrt{y}\right)\left(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}\right) = 0
$$

Which in turn gives you the same conclusion as Calvin pointed out